# .NET MVC5 Encoding and Decoding ID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

My routes works like Controller/Action/Id
But I wont want to show that Id part directly coz its a specific personal number ,
How Can I Encode and Decode that Id
Thanks for Helps..

Comment: The best practice is to use Guid for ID in your URL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class User {

   public User()
   {
       UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
   }

   public Guid UserId {get; set;}
   public int PersonalNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Your URL will looks like:

```
http://www.website.com/controller/action/73b56796-6a41-4433-b5c1-c20daaa17fc9
```